# Force Https CentOS Web Panel

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, centos6, vps

I am using `CentOS Web Panel` and trying to redirect to `https` also when someone hits the `http` link. I am only able to open both `https` when i type 
`https://domain.com`.

Using the below rules solves my problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NS,R,L]
```

But i need to add this to all the sites in my server.

How can i automatically redirect all the sites in my server?

Does any method other than `.htaccess redirection` exists to redirect to https?

Hope i have clearly stated the problem.

Comment: In order to do that you need to add the rule directly to the apache config file and not in .htaccess where it will be more global and not directory specific. You will also need to use the `HTTP_HOST` var instead of the domain name if you want it to work for other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that using the `.htaccess` is the easiest method to solve the problem.

Adding the below mentioned codes in `.htaccess` gives the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NS,R,L]
```

***If there is any other easiest method than `.htaccess` redirection exists anyone could help edit this answer.***

Answer (score 0):

as said by panama jack

u should use it in your vhosts.conf at yourdomain:yourport/index.php?module=vhost_tpl

then u rebuild your vhosts and the change will be active for all your domains

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]